# Haskell Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, kinda 2 days since I study Haskell, and I want to do a project with files. I did it already in c++ and now I want to do it in Haskell too.
A little part of project is about a library, where I can register a book and a person. Now I want to put book code into a file.txt but to store it as int, not as String, because I have to search and compare this code , with other codes later, and will be easier to compare.
Here is my code, and I receive the following error *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse. Does anyone know how to solve this please?

```
 import System.IO                      
 main = do
    putStrLn "Please put book details"
    putStr "Code: "
    code <- getLine
    let code1 = read code
    appendFile "book.txt" ("Cod:" ++ code1 ++ "\n")
```

Comment: Might be because you haven't told it how you want it to read it. You usually need to use a type annotation when using `read`. How is is supposed to know what type you want it to interpret `code` as? In Haskell, when in doubt, add type annotations. Seriously, remember that. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Wait, `code` is already a String. Why are you `read`ing it?

Comment: Because I seen that in some tutorials....they said that by using "let code1 = read code" it will be converted to int :\

Comment: It's been about a year since I've written Haskell, but doesn't `read` take a String and return an object? Or in other words, the opposite of `show`? Since you're concating `code1` on the next line, you expect it to be a String, but that's already what `getLine` returns, so it should already be the correct type. `read`ing should only be necessary when the type being written to file isn't a String.

Comment: The problem here is that `"Cod:" ++ code1` forces `code1` to be a string. So `read` is going from string to string, and that fails.

Comment: `let code1 = read code` creates an int only if `code` is defined or later inferred to be an `int`. `read` can return values of many different types, depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, problem is solved now :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails since you're attempting to `read` a String as a String.

`read` is used to parse a String as an object. To parse a String as a String though, you need to add explicit quotes around the String being parsed. Failing to do so will result in the error that you got. You can test this by adding `"`s around the input when your program asks for it. It should work.

Do you expect `code1` to be an int? If that's the case, there's 2 problems (and a couple ways to solve them) :

1. You need to tell `read` what type you want it to parse the string as. To do that, use a type annotation. Add `:: int` after `read code`.
2. Since you can't concatenate an int, change `code1` in your last line to `(show code1)` to convert it back to a String.

The problem with the above way is you're converting from, then to a String. You could avoid any converting by keeping it as a String by skipping the `read` altogether:

```
import System.IO                      
 main = do
    putStrLn "Please put book details"
    putStr "Code: "
    code <- getLine
    # Check user's input to ensure it's correct. 
    appendFile "book.txt" ("Cod:" ++ code)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works....you know what I can't explain myself? 2 h ago, I did it like this, but it didn't worked, and now it works just great.

Comment: @ClaudiuM Haskell is, by definition, very consistent. There must have been something different if it wasn't working, but is now. I'm glad it works though.

Comment: Do you know how to access "code" variable if I'm inside 2 if statements for example? Because I get the following error when I try to acces it "    • Variable not in scope: code :: String
    • Perhaps you meant one of these:
        ‘cos’ (imported from Prelude), ‘mod’ (imported from Prelude)"
I know need a kind of global declaration for code, just like we use in C++ or Java...but how to do that here in Haskell?

Comment: @ClaudiuM Post a link to a pastebin / gist.github with the code. I'm not sure what you mean. I'll gladly help if you if I see some code.

Comment: @ClaudiuM Are you talking about accessing the `code` inside the `if number == 1` block? If you think about it, that doesn't make any sense. If the user enters "3", the 1 block will never execute, so `code` won't exist. Create a function that asks the user to enter a code, and use that in both places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113269/discussion-between-carcigenicate-and-claudiu-m).